# Control Id for access to context menu of in-chart shapes

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office, vsto, office-interop

Let me quickly explain my requirement.

I am working with charts in powerpoint, word and excel.
These charts have in-chart shapes (shapes that can be added to the chart by going to one of the contextual tabs -> chart tools -> layout tab.In my case, a line on the chart (which is contained by the chart and moves with the chart).
I want to access the context menu for this line shape.

I have been looking at the control-ids list for the office 2010 apps. I can't find anything. I know for a fact i can access the context menus for independent shapes, i.e. the shapes that are not contained within other shapes (since I am doing that already).

Anyone have any suggestions, or is this a limitation imposed by Microsoft?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not all control IDs are available for developers. See [Office 2010 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627) for idMso values.